# How to include JQuery from node_modules, except from cdn in Laravel 5.8 app?

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm, package

I have a Laravel app and I need to include all scripts from my npm packages. Fro Datatables and other stuff to work, I need JQuery to work. I had implemented JQuery from CDN earlier, now want to use it from my node packages.

I have installed it using npm

```
npm install jquery
```

But now I cannot use them and in chrome-dev-tool it is showing $ as undefined symbol.

my bootstrap.js file in resources folder is as follows and my Laravel mix build is getting successful while running

```
npm run dev
```

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default; //dont know working or not
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); // Present earlier

    require('bootstrap'); // working
    require('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'); // working
    require('datatables.net-bs4'); // not working

    window.toastr = require('toastr'); // not working
    window.DataTable = require('datatables.net'); // not working as jQuery is not working
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios'); // present from earlier
... continues
```

I have tried

`include('jquery')` ,

`include('jquery/dist/jquery')` ,

`include('jquery/dist/jquery.js')`

but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to require jquery in your bootstrap.js

```
require('jquery);
```

In your app.scss try this:

```
//DataTable
@import '~datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css';
```

If after this your jQuery and your DataTable still not working, go to your node_modules directory and check if the jquery package and your datatables package are ok. If not, run the command

```
npm update
```

and reinstall your packages.

Comment: Have tried everything. Require, import, @import everything. And packages are there in  node modules folder

Comment: If I include cdn in header, and tried to remove require statement, also my application fails. Dont know why.

Comment: Are you declaring app.js at the bottom of your layout?

Comment: No. I am declaring at the top of my head tag

Comment: Try to declare at the bottom of your layout following by stack('scripts'), after all DOM elements are loaded, like this: <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@stack('scripts')